# Gatsby image mystery

Tags: gatsby

I'm using Gatsby + Strapi stack. Images uploaded to strapi and then downloaded via gatsby-source-strapi plugin since gatsby-image only works with local images.

```
GraphQL query:
    allStrapiRestaurant {
      edges {
        node {
          logo{
            childImageSharp {
              fluid{
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }  
            }
            publicURL
          }
    ...
```

Query works as expected, data is there

```
{props.data.allStrapiRestaurant.edges.map((restaurant) => (
    <div key={restaurant.node.id}>
       <Img fluid={restaurant.node.logo.childImageSharp.fluid} />
    </div>     
  ))}
```

This comes up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactstandin__key' of undefined

node_modules/react-hot-loader/dist/react-hot-loader.development.js:1229


  1226 |   return idsByType.get(type);
  1227 | };
  1228 | var isProxyType = function isProxyType(type) {
> 1229 |   return type[PROXY_KEY];
  1230 | };
  1231 | 
  1232 | var getProxyById = function getProxyById(id) {
```

Struggling with this more than 2 days already. Any ideas (except not using Strapi+Gatsby :)?

Comment: Are you using emotion?

Comment: Please expand your example implementation as one could think that you're trying to access an array without mapping over it

Comment: @LekoArts updated

Comment: @ksav no, I'm not, nothing extra at all, there is basically no app there yet, just this page and some pain

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having exact same issue with the fluid settings although i am getting the images from contentful. Regardless, it looks like I am dong everything right, and getting this odd error.

Comment: @Starfs nope, still nothing, sorry

Comment: I think this may be a Gatsby issue where we cannot create class components (such as Img) in loops for some reason?

Comment: Having the same issue, not with Strapi and not creating `<Img/>` components in a loop either, but with image nodes created by a custom transformer plugin.  Exactly the same error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was calling

```
import Img from "gatsby"
```

instead of

```
import Img from "gatsby-image"
```

.. it was so obvious that it didn't occur to me. And I never received a relevant error because I supposed gatsby has a component you can import called Img maybe ... ??

Comment: I'm importing from gatsby-image :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue on the Gatsby repo that seems to be related, but it may or may not be helpful to you.  It seems there can be numerous situations in which this error might be thrown, and just as many solutions.  Nothing in here solved my case, but you might find some inspiration (or at least some things to try) here:

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16481

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution for me is using the default html img tag with the `src` prop of `fluid`:

```js
<img src={restaurant.node.logo.childImageSharp.fluid.src} />
```

which does not enable us to use Gatsby's extra features, but not crashing at least.

Comment: Yeah, I've used that too, but looking for a solution to use gatsby's Image with all it's power